# regular expression in bash with grep

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I am trying to print strings that contain any number of '=' signs in it. For that i am using the following command in bash

```
cat myfile | grep '^.*=+.*$'
```

I am writing ^ and $ for start and end of string

.* for any numnber of any character.

=+ for one or more equal(=) character.

But it doesn't show any output when executed.

But if i do simply:

```
cat myfile | grep '='
```

I get the desired output Why is this so?

What am i  missing here ?

Comment: See [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you're using isn't a basic posix regex. For example it tries to match the `+` literally.

You should try using

```sh
cat myfile | grep -E '^.*=+.*$'
```

the `-E` is for extended regular expressions.

Wikipedia has a nice comparison of posix basic and extended regular expressions where you also can see that `+` is only a meta character in the extended version: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_extended